# How to configure sqlite of django project with pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I have deployed my project to pythonanywhere.
It is working locally.
But with pythonanywhere I am getting no such table exception.
I have configured sqllite as in this [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/)
Just mentioned to generate the sqlite file using runmigrations.
I have changed the settings.py to use os.path.join at that Database section also but still same issue.

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'todo_todo' doesn't exist")


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

tried with os.path.join also but same error.

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    memo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    important=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I migrated individual apps also.

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
```

Comment: Did you use their console and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes done already but still getting error

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting? And also the `settings.py`, just the part, where the DB config is.

Comment: I have created a model and the error is table not found "appname_modelname"

Comment: I changed to sql and tried now..it seems my model is not created,only admin tables are created

Comment: I don't know how but it is working now once I create a new mysql instance in the pythonanywhere and using that